# Pick Video And Pics from photo gallary please

Tags: ios, iphone, video, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm desperately trying to add video picking option to my app. The app can take a picture and select pictures but it cannot select video file. I want the users to be able to select video from the photo library just as easily as they can select a photo. But most people I have asked seem to think it is not possible. But of course, it is not. I have used many app with this feature. Or this is not something I can do with Xcode?

```
  }
    let actionsheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction) in
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary){
            let mypickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            mypickerController.delegate = self
            mypickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(mypickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }))
    actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction) in
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
            let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            myPickerController.delegate = self
            myPickerController.sourceType = .camera
            self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }))
    actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(actionsheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func onSaveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print("screenshot pressed")

    //let appDelegate: AppDelegate? = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    //appDelegate?.myInterstitial = appDelegate?.createAndLoadInterstitial()

    if firstImage.image == nil{
        GlobalFunction.sharedManager.setWhiteBackground(selectView: firstImage)
    }
    if secondImage.image == nil{
        GlobalFunction.sharedManager.setWhiteBackground(selectView: secondImage)
    }
    if thirdImage.image == nil{
        GlobalFunction.sharedManager.setWhiteBackground(selectView: thirdImage)
    }
    let image = GlobalFunction.sharedManager.takeScreenshot(theView: backView)//takeScreenshot(theView: backView)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(image(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}

@IBAction func onCancelButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainVC") as! ViewController
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func onAddButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainVC") as! ViewController
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
@objc func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSErrorPointer, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async{

        self.showAlertView(message: "Your story has been saved to your Camera Roll", completionHandler: { (a) in

            let appDelegate: AppDelegate? = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
            appDelegate?.myInterstitial = appDelegate?.createAndLoadInterstitial()

        })

        //UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "Your story has been saved to your Camera Roll", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Close").show()
    }
}

func takeScreenshot(theView: UIView) -> UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(theView.bounds.size, true, 0.0)
    theView.drawHierarchy(in: theView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image!
}

func circleCropDidCancel() {
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}

func circleCropDidCropImage(_ image: UIImage) {
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    if selected == 1{
        firstImage.image = image
    }else if selected == 2{
        secondImage.image = image
    }else if selected == 3{
        thirdImage.image = image
    }

}
```

}

Comment: One choice is to look at the [documentation for UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller) or google. Another choice is to do nothing and scream URGENT. The first is better.

Answer (score 0):

UIImagePickerController has a [`mediaTypes` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619173-mediatypes). It determines what kind of media the picker can pick. You are not setting `mypickerController.mediaTypes` to include videos.

Comment: I did find the code below in Apple documentation. "To designate the movie capture interface, or to indicate that only movies should be displayed when browsing saved media, use the kUTTypeMovie identifier in a statement like this:
myImagePickerController.mediaTypes =
    [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

To designate all available media types for a source, use a statement like this:
myImagePickerController.mediaTypes =
    [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];  "

Comment: My code is written in an If, let Statement... Which code do I replace with this one ----:
myImagePickerController.mediaTypes =
    [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];